# Why can't SSH use my public key?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to figure out why I can't get SSH public key authentication working with my school's UNIX server. I obviously don't have root access, but I've attached verbose SSH output and permissions of both client and host .ssh directories, and ssh-copy-id showing that a key was uploaded. The content of Local's id_rsa.pub and Server's authorized_keys files matches exactly. What do I need to fix?

```
LOCALUSERNAME@LOCALUSERNAMEsMBP ~/.ssh  ls -al
total 56
drwx------    7 LOCALUSERNAME  staff   224 May 27 20:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 120 LOCALUSERNAME  staff  3840 May 27 20:07 ../
-rw-------    1 LOCALUSERNAME  staff  1766 Jun  3  2015 github_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 LOCALUSERNAME  staff   399 Jun  3  2015 github_rsa.pub
-rw-------    1 LOCALUSERNAME  staff  1675 Sep  8  2018 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 LOCALUSERNAME  staff   401 Sep  8  2018 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 LOCALUSERNAME  staff  9244 May 25 21:01 known_hosts

ssh-copy-id MYUSERNAME@SERVER
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
MYUSERNAME@SERVER's password:

Number of key(s) added:        1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'MYUSERNAME@SERVER'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

ssh -v MYUSERNAME@SERVER
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to SERVER port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to SERVER:22 as 'MYUSERNAME'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:~~SOMESTRING~~
debug1: Host 'SERVER' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:25
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:~~REDACTED ID_RSA~~
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:~~REDACTED ID_RSA~~
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
MYUSERNAME@SERVER's password:


MYUSERNAME@SERVER  ~/.ssh  ls -al
total 7
drwx------  2 MYUSERNAME users 2048 Sep  8  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 MYUSERNAME wheel 4096 May 27 20:07 ..
-rw-------  1 MYUSERNAME users  802 May 27 20:01 authorized_keys
```

Comment: It's possible that the remote system is not configured for publickey authentication. You could ask the system administrators.

Comment: Or possibly `authorized_keys` is not where that system looks for authorized keys.

Comment: All those `Trying private key: /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_XXX` lines seem suspiciously important.

Comment: @JeffSchaller is there some way I could check or find out on my own if publickey authentication is blocked?

Comment: Since you can login, maybe you could check the server config file (`cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, perhaps).

Comment: As the remote system says `Authentications that can continue: publickey, ...` it's definitely configured for publickey authentication. Your public key was tried and didn't work, so log in with the password to the remote machine, do `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, double check syntax and make sure there's a line in there that matches your local `/Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (note `.pub` at end). If you can, you can also try reading the `sshd` log messages on the remote machine, or ask the system administrator to do so to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: You may need to restore the selinux security context. Although `ssh-copy-id` does this it may not have found the command in the default PATH.  Try `restorecon -R .ssh` using `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` in your PATH.